# Add model administration to Active Admin - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm fairly new to Rails and ActiveAdmin.

I'd like to have an interface much like Django's admin, with my app models, so I can administer products, and other stuff.

So far I have the `admin_users` url where I can add or delete admin users to my app, that's wonderful.

I'm using Rails 3, and I was wondering if I can add a new menu besides Users so I can manage other models from the `dashboard`

I've tried `rails generate active_admin:resource Product`

It creates a file called `product.rb` on `app/admin/` but it doesn't works, this is my `Product` model `product.rb`

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
belongs_to :category
has_many :line_items
has_many :orders, through: :line_items

validates_presence_of :category_id, :name, :price_cents
attr_accessible :avatar
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

attr_accessor :price

attr_accessible :category_id, :description, :image, :name, :price_cents, :upc_code, :price, :taxable

def price
  price_cents/100.0 if price_cents
end

def price= price
  self.price_cents = (price.to_f*100).round
end

end
```

I don't know, what am I doing wrong?

Any ideas?

Comment: hey check this http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin

Comment: Awesome @Arv bookmarked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To register your `Product` model, run:

```
rails generate active_admin:resource Product
```

This creates a file at `app/admin/product.rb` for configuring the resource. **Refresh your web browser** to see the interface.

Please take a look at [Active Admin Documentation](http://activeadmin.info/docs/documentation.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes, I did that but didn't work before, lol, Thank you very much!

Comment: You are most welcome :) I am glad that its working for you now :-)

Answer (score 3):

Under `app/admin` your product.rb file register the model. I would look something like

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  :category_id, :description, :image, :name, :price_cents, :upc_code, :price, :taxable

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :description
    column :name
    column :price_cents
    actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Product Details" do
      f.input :price
      f.input :name
      f.input :description
      # more fields
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Look at the [documentation](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank You, I'm going to have this as a personal documentation, Thanks a lot!